# Enable php_ssh2 library in PHP 7 on Windows 10 system

Tags: php, ssh, windows-10, php-7.2

I tried to enable php_ssh2 library in PHP 7 on windows 10 system. I have tried many ways, but nothing helps me.

When I tried to access "ssh2_connect()" function, it shows the below error
 "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()".

OS: Windows 10

PHP Version : 7.2.4 (Wamp Server 3.1.3)

Please anyone help me on this?

Answer (score -3):

1) Download extension on click https://phpfashion.com/php-ssh2-dll-for-php-5-6-and-7-0

Which compatible with your system like your system is 64 bit and php version is 7 then download php_ssh2.dll for PHP 7.0 x64,

2) In php.ini add below line 
extension= php_ssh2.dll

3) restart your xampp or wampp.

Comment: I did the same. But still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: no. I didn't get any error in error_logs. But in screen i'm getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()" error.

Comment: I wouldn't trust that phpfashion.com website. Looks suspicious to me, not a genuine software source.